# How to Merge two datasets with different indexes but one common ID factor?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am working with two distinct datasets: one regarding COVID-19 statistics and one with demographic characteristics of a city.

The covid19 one, namely `covid.df` looks as follows:

**Note: Date, City ID, City, and State are all indexes**

| Date | City ID | City | State | Population mean | Population_2019 mean | Confirmed_rate_100k mean | Confirmed_rate_100k std | death_rate mean | death_rate std | new_confirmed | new_deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02 | 120385 | Los Angeles | CA | 9559699 | 45959669 | 0.653 | 0.556 | 0.6 | 0.01 | 33 | 5 |
| 2020-02 | 120054 | Houtson | Texas | 3304040 | 3343560 | 0.543 | 0.043 | 22.34 | 1.6 | 60 | 9 |
| ... | ... | .... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-05 | 120385 | Los Angeles | CA | 9559483 | 45966549 | 0.672 | 0.032 | 2.3 | 0.5 | 22 | 12 |

The one with demographic information, `demo.df` includes the following

| City ID | HDI | Education | Mobility | Poverty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120385 | 0.54 | 72.5 | 55.522 | 33.21 |
| 120054 | 0.33 | 66.2 | 76.433 | 12.504 |

I would like to include the information from `demo.df` on `covid.df`, however, given the different indexes for the two datasets, the `concat()` function has been giving me a hard time.

How can I merge the two such datasets such that `covid.df` looks like this:

| Date | City ID | City | State | HDI | Education | Mobility | Poverty | Population mean | Population_2019 mean | Confirmed_rate_100k mean | Confirmed_rate_100k std | death_rate mean | death_rate std | new_confirmed | new_deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02 | 120385 | Los Angeles | CA | 0.54 | 72.5 | 55.522 | 33.21 | 9559699 | 45959669 | 0.653 | 0.556 | 0.6 | 0.01 | 33 | 5 |
| 2020-02 | 120054 | Houston | TX | 0.33 | 66.2 | 76.433 | 12.504 | 3304040 | 3343560 | 0.543 | 0.043 | 22.34 | 1.6 | 60 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-05 | 120385 | Los Angeles | CA | 0.54 | 72.5 | 55.522 | 33.21 | 9559483 | 45966549 | 0.672 | 0.032 | 2.3 | 0.5 | 22 | 12 |

Thank you!

Comment: `reset_index()` on each dataframe and then use `merge` on `City ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need this:

```py
covid = covid.merge(demo, how='left', on='City ID')
```

For example, suppose we have this input (notice the different indexes of `88, 99` and `'fish', 'fowl'`):

```
covid.df:
       Date  City ID          City    State  Population mean  Population_2019 mean  Confirmed_rate_100k mean  Confirmed_rate_100k std  death_rate mean  death_rate std  new_confirmed  new_deaths
88  2020-02   120385  Los Angeles       CA           9559699              45959669                     0.653                    0.556             0.60            0.01             33           5
99  2020-02   120054      Houtson    Texas           3304040               3343560                     0.543                    0.043            22.34            1.60             60           9
demo.df:
      City ID   HDI  Education  Mobility  Poverty
fish   120385  0.54       72.5    55.522   33.210
fowl   120054  0.33       66.2    76.433   12.50
```

The output will be

```
      Date  City ID          City    State  Population mean  Population_2019 mean  Confirmed_rate_100k mean  ...  death_rate std  new_confirmed  new_deaths   HDI  Education  Mobility  Poverty
0  2020-02   120385  Los Angeles       CA           9559699              45959669                     0.653  ...            0.01             33           5  0.54       72.5    55.522   33.210
1  2020-02   120054      Houtson    Texas           3304040               3343560                     0.543  ...            1.60             60           9  0.33       66.2    76.433   12.504

[2 rows x 16 columns]
```